# Building a dynamic MongoDB query with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Given the schema

```
Event = new Schema({
  type: String,
  action: String,
  cause: String,
  userId: String
)};
```

I want to query documents in my collection with a POST request.  The request contains an array of types, actions, causes, userIds.  An array may be empty (meaning I don't want to include it in the query), or it could have values.

How do I write a function that will query the collection based on dynamic keys and values?

I have tried several variations including:

```
...
var query = {}
for (var key in req.body) {
  if (req.body[key] && req.body[key].length > 0) {
     query[key] = {$in: req.body[key]};
  }
}
Event.find({query}).exec(...);
```

The query executes fine but never produces results.  When I console.log(query), I don't see expected results.

Ex:  I see `{'type': {'$in': ['a', 'b']}}` ($in surrounded with quotes)
 instead of `{'type': {$in: ['a', 'b']}}`

Comment: seems like there is a typo in val query = {}, Shouldn't it be let of var instead of val?

Comment: There is nothing else(except the val) wrong with your code. It works fine in my console. Make sure req.body is having what you expect.

Comment: @NidhinDavid maybe i am returning results wrong?  `.exec(function(err, rows) { res.status(200).send(rows); });` . But even when I log the rows, it is empty

Comment: The quotes don't matter around '$in', it's legal to put quotes around an object property